# make option to suppress output

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm on Debian 12 writing a **Makefile** to simplify some tasks:

```
todo:
    su - user -c "/mypath/dothis"
```

Now I can see the standard output from that task if run with:

```
make todo
```

I've checked in **man make** and found **-s silent**: but this hide only the command, is there a way suppress output or this is the only way:

```
make todo >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: make invokes a shell script.  It has no control over what the shell script does, and there's no option in make to redirect all the output of the shell script to `/dev/null`.  If you want to do this you need to put it into the script, so for example you'd change your recipe to be `su - user -c '/mypath/dothis >/dev/null 2>&1'`

Comment: A Makefile is intended for automating a build procecess, i.e. creating files from source files. Your Makefile does not follow this use case but uses a phony target to run an arbitrary command. Why don't you use a shell script or shell function instead of a Makefile?

Comment: Maybe this is not a good practice but I've found out  more useful to have a makefile inside a folder project that execute different commands based on that project but with same invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be to make the recipe output to `/dev/null`:

```
todo_quiet:
   @su - user -c "/mypath/dothis" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

and then run `make todo_quite`

You could also do a command line parameter as so:

```
Q := $(if $(V),,@)
Q_SUFFIX := $(if $(V),,> /dev/null 2>&1)

.PHONY: todo

todo:
   $(Q)su - user -c "/mypath/dothis" $(Q_SUFFIX)
```

Where you would run `make todo` to compile quietly, and `make todo V=1` to do it verbosely.   If you want to suppress all output from any make recipe, you would have to pipe make's output to `/dev/null`...

Comment: You don't need any custom tricks to conditionally disable `@`. Make already has built-in `--debug=print` (and `--trace`) that disables it.